# controller values are not binding to HTML in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a single HTML file for 2 controllers. I am using one array in HTML with name `availableCountries[]` in both controllers. When I  click dropdown in a controller its showing array values and I am storing those values in an array and passing the array to the 2nd controller to display from the second controller. But, the values are not displaying in HTML, but showing in Controller. Any idea on this?

Comment: Could you show the relevant parts of code for both controllers and both views, precising which one is binding and which one is not?

Comment: Are the controllers on nested elements or sibling elements?

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies).

Comment: U should show your code to make it clear for others

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am also facing the same problem. HTML Is similar to this

```
<div class="form-group mar-bottom-6" data-ng-repeat="multipleContentsData in requestAdditionalCountries[type.Identity.ItemId].multipleContents track by $index"><label for="additionalcountry">Additonal Country</label>
```

In one controller I am forming the array as

```
var multipleContents = {
                "availableCountry": availableCountries
            };
          $scope.requestAdditionalCountries[$scope.type.Identity.ItemId].multipleContents.push(multipleContents);
```

In another controller as

```
multipleContents = {
                    "SelectedCountry": angular.copy(availableCountries),
                    "availableCountry": angular.copy($scope.countries)
                };
                $scope.requestAdditionalCountries[$scope.finalJobRequest.jobRequestObject.requestObjects[reqObjIndex].Identity.ItemId].multipleContents.push(angular.copy(multipleContents));
```

Both the controllers are sibling.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19662759)

Comment: I posted another question can u answer to that